# Building UITableView from deep JSON structure

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

So guys, I'm facing a problem that I haven't been able to figure out. I'm using a UITableView to display data that I'm collecting from a JSON object that's been converted to a dictionary.

```
{
  "start_from": "2014-08-10",
  "list_tags": {
    "2014-08-12": {
      "0": [
        {
          "id": "5",
          "tag": "555"
        }
      ],
      "1": [
        {
          "id": "5",
          "tag": "556"
        }
      ],
      "-1": [
        {
          "id": "5",
          "tag": "557"
        }
      ]
    },
    "2014-08-10": {
      "0": [
        {
          "id": "5",
          "tag": "558"
        },
        {
          "id": "5",
          "tag": "565"
        },
        {
          "id": "5",
          "tag": "566"
        }
      ],
      "1": [
        {
          "id": "5",
          "tag": "559"
        }
      ],
      "-1": [
        {
          "id": "5",
          "tag": "560"
        }
      ]
    },
    "2014-08-14": {
      "0": [
        {
          "id": "5",
          "tag": "561"
        }
      ],
      "1": [
        {
          "id": "5",
          "tag": "562"
        },
        {
          "id": "5",
          "tag": "564"
        }
      ],
      "-1": [
        {
          "id": "5",
          "tag": "563"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you look at the json structure, it follows something like

Dictionary -> list_tags -> { particular date (one of many dates) -> { particular array (one of three identifier values -1,0,1) -> { particular object (can be several) }}

I'm using a tableview, with formatted dates as headers. The challenge here is to display all the objects inside the arrays (-1,0,1) under the same respective header. Since each array can have multiple objects inside them, its complicated to find out how many objects exists under one date, and thus, one header.

Using enumeration, I obtained the number of objects for a certain date.

So my titleForHeader uses

```
self.listTagsKeys[section];
```

which returns the number of objects under all arrays, for a certain date.

And my number of sections is

```
[self.listTags count];
```

I have my number of rows using a dictionary mapped with [Date : Number Of Rows]

```
[self.tagsForDates valueForKey:[self.listTagsKeys objectAtIndex:section]];
```

The challenge I'm facing here is how to display the data for the tableview cells under the same header, since I'm not able to access the data directly.

If I'm doing this wrong, please let me know so that I'm not heading in the wrong direction.
I'd be terrible grateful if someone could show me how to use an iterator for this situation, rather than simply pointing out that this could be fixed using an iterator, or help me figure out a way to do this, or organize the data better from the JSON structure.

Let me know if this is too confusing, so I'll be able to explain it better.

Cheers!

The Section will be the date, and the rows will be all the objects from (-1,0,1) for each date, under that section. Since each of these objects has a unique identifier as a parent i.e -1,0,1, I'm not sure how I'll be able to tell which rows are of a certain identifier.

So 2014-08-10 will have 5 rows, but with one of three images (one for -1, one for 0,one for 1) as its imageview. To be able to display this image in the imageview for a certain row, I need to know what type it is.

Comment: It doesn't look too hard using nested arrays, but I am not 100% on what you want under each each date heading - perhaps if you could update your question with an idea of what the table would look like - i.e. Under 2014-08-10 would there be 3 rows (0,1,-1) or 5 rows (all of the items under 0,1,-1) ?

Comment: The Section will be the date, and the rows will be all the objects from (-1,0,1) for each date, under that section. Since each of these objects has a unique identifier as a parent i.e -1,0,1, I'm not sure how I'll be able to tell which rows are of a certain identifier. So 2014-08-10 will have 5 rows, but with one of three images (one for -1, one for 0,one for 1) as its imageview.
 
I'm just getting the hang of stackoverflow, so I'm not completely sure of where to add updates or edits.

Comment: You should be able to click "edit" below your question

Comment: Just build an array to map the rows the way you want them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by creating an object to store the section and row object. A simple NSObject subclass something like this -

MySectionObject.h:

```
@class MySectionObject;

@interface MySectionObject: NSObject {

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *date;
@property (readonly,nonatomic) NSArray *rowData; 

-(id)initWithDate:(NSDate)date;
-(void)addRow:(MyRowObject *)row;

@end
```

mySectionObject.m:

```
@interface MySectionObject: ()

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *rows;

@end

@implementation MySectionObject

   -(id)initWithDate:(NSDate *)date 
   {
        if (self=[super init]) {
            _date=date;
            _rows=[NSMutableArray new];
        }

        return self;
   }

   -(void)addRow(MyRowObject *)row
   {
       [self.rows addObject:row];
   }

   -(NSArray *)rowData {
   {
       return [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.rows];
   }

@end
```

MyRowObject.h:

```
@interface MyRowObject: NSObject {

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *tag;
@property NSInteger imageType 

-(id)initWithType:(NSInteger)type id:(NSString *)id tag:(NSString *)tag;

@end
```

myRowObject.m:

```
@implementation MyRowObject

   -(id)initWithType:(NSInteger)type id:(NSString *)id tag:(NSString *)tag
   {
        if (self=[super init]) {
            _imageType=type;
            _id=id;
            _tag=tag;
        }

        return self;
   }

@end
```

I have used strings for the two properties as I wasn't sure if they were numbers or that was just your example data.

Then you can simply enumerate your JSON to produce a nested array -

```
self.tableData=[NSMutableArray new];   // This is a property that stores the data for your tableview
NSDictionary *listTags = [myJson objectForKey:@"list_tags"];

for (NSString *date in listTags) {

   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
   NSDate *sectionDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];

   MySectionObject *section=[MySectionObject alloc]initWithDate:sectionDate];

   NSDictionary *listTagDict = (NSDictionary *)[listTags objectForKey:date];

   for (NSString *imageType in listTagDict) {
       NSInteger *type=[imageTypes integerValue];
       NSArray *rows=[listTagDict objectForKey:imageType];
       for (NSDictionary *rowDict in rows) {
          NSString *id=(NSString *)[rowDict objectForKey:@"id"];
          NSString *tag=(NSString *)[rowDict objectForKey:@"tag"];
          MyRowObject *row=[MyRowObject alloc] initWithType:type id:id tag:tag]];
          [section addRow:row];
       }
   }

   [self.tableData addObject:section];
}
```

Now the number of sections is given by `self.tableData.count` and the number of each rows in a section is given by `[self.tableData objectAtIndex:sectionNumber].rowData.count`

You can get the data for a section header using `MySectionObject *s=[self.tableData objectAtIndex:sectionNumber]` and the value for a row using

```
 MySectionObject *s=[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
 MyRowObject *r=[s.rowData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Not only have you fixed my problem, you've shown me how to do this so that I can always deal with it on my own. Terrific. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(void) ViewDidLoad
  {
     //json is the data you posted;    
     NSDictionary * dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
     NSMutableArray *datesArr = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     for(NSDictionary *d in [dict valueForKey:@"list_tags"])
         [datesArr addObject:d];
     NSMutableArray *endItems = [NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //list of all dates under list_tags
     NSMutableArray *rootItems = [NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //array of dictionary(id,tags)
     for(int i =0 i<[datesArr count]; i++)
     {
        [[datesArr objectAtIndex:i] enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {
        [endItems addObject:key];
        NSArray *roots = [datesArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [[roots objectAtIndex:i] enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {
               [rootItems addObject:object];
            }];
        }];
     }
  }

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {
      return [endItems count];
  }

 -(NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
     return [endItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
       for(int i=0; i<[endItems count];i++)
        {
           if(i==section)
             //i could n't analyse how to get count for each sections.. is bit complicated
        }

    }

-(UITableViewCell *) responsesTableViewConfiguration:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ //Your Cell implementation
   Cell.title.text = [[rootItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"];
   Cell.subtitle.text = [[rootItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"tag"];
}
```

Comment: I tried this implementation, but I wasn't able to access the elements at the deepest nest, with respect to its parent type. I used @Paul's implementation and it works exactly like I needed it to.